# Samaba - where are my Win10 sahres mounted?

Tags: mount, samba

I've got Samba running under 16.04.3LTS. I can get to my Win10 machine's shares, and access them directly (view a jpg, play a wav, etc.). But... how do I tell, for example. kdenlive where smb://seven is mounted? As an exmple, I want to open, in kdenlive, /mnt/samba/seven/foo.jpg. But I can't figure out where smb://seven is mounted. I looked in /mnt and /media - nothing. "mount" doesn't show any signs of my Win10 shares.

Answer (score 0):

KDE accesses the share by talking to the remote server directly, it doesn't actually mount the remote share via the kernel. This is why it doesn't show up in mount on the standard Linux file hierarchy.

To mount the share, you need to run the mount command manually. E.g.

```
mount -t cifs //seven/share /mnt/samba
```